OpenMP deadlock when it has a omp for loop insed a normal loop
Simple problem, when I try to run the following code I have a deadlock.
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_KEY 1000

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int i, k;
  int num = 100;

#pragma omp parallel
  {
    for (k = 0; k < num; k++) {
#pragma omp for
      for (i = 0; i < MAX_KEY; i++);     
    }
    printf("----------%i\n", omp_get_thread_num());
  }
  return 0;
}

In my mind, this code is actually meant to run. If I remove the implicit barrier, it runs. But, I want to understand why it doesn't.

You should really define variable close to they use. AFAIK, this is strongly recommanded by the C++ ISO committee. This is also important in OpenMP since it can impact whether variable are shared or private. Here, variables like i and k are shared in the parallel section (by default) because they are defined before it. They are probably not in the parallel loop because AFAIK iterators are always private by default. The thing is k is shared anyway in the parallel loop. Thus, this code does not have a "deadlock" but a race condition.

You must either define k and i as private in the omp parallel section or just move the variable declaration closer. The later is better. By the way, in C++, the standard is to move the declaration in the for statement as much as possible (e.g. for (int k = 0; k < num; k++)). It is also recommanded in C++ to use constexpr variables instead of preprocessor defines (eg. for MAX_KEY). Using const for num is also a good practice. Finally, <stdio.h> should be <cstdio> in C++. C and C++ are different languages.

To be a bit more precise, the application has a deadlock caused by a data race. The deadlock is caused by executing the for directive with a different number of iterations from the different threads. Therefore, the thread with the least number of iterations in the k loop will reach the barrier at the end of the parallel region, while the other threads will be stuck in the barrier at the end of the for loop. As Jerome pointed out, the different number of iterations in the k loop is caused by k being shared. Since multiple threads write to k without synchronization, you have a data race on k.

The difference between data race and race condition is important in different ways. Data race is defined as undefined behavior in C, C++, and OpenMP. Race condition is not. Most tools (TSan/Valgrind) will report data race, but not race condition. If you would declare k as atomic<int> k, you would solve the data race and remove the undefined behavior coming from the data race. The random number of implicit barriers would still cause undefined behavior for OpenMP and lead to the deadlock.
